# How do I prevent editing of specific cells but allow the viewer to only select them?

Tags: excel

How do I prevent editing of specific cells but allow the viewer to only select them ? **Excel version 2007**

The method I tried is I locked all cells in worksheet, but unlocked those specific cells. In protection rules I allowed only the selection of them. This allowed them to be selected but also allowed them to be edited too.

I don't want them edited as their contents have to be static and displayed somewhere else in the worksheet. I designed it such that selecting them and pressing F9 allows to calculate elsewhere a set of values for current specific cell. A big table is also possible since their contents are all static/fixed, but the rows and columns in it would be very huge and not very readable/tractable.

Next I tried the reverse way. I unlocked the whole worksheet and locked those specific cells and in protection I allowed locked cells to be selected, but unfortunately it allows also selecting unlocked cells. This is problematic because the set of values calculated elsewhere come out as garbage. The proper input values they need for calculation are in those specific cells.

**So How do I allow selection but prevent editing of cells in a worksheet ?**

Comment: What version of excel do you use? 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016?

Comment: @Kathara oops, I should have given the version earlier, Excel 2007

Comment: I tried with Excel 2016 and it would have been so easy. As I do not own the 2007 version (which I believe was one of the buggiest versions) I can only instruct you how to do it in 2016. But first: what option did you select when locking the workbook? What options do you have?

Comment: @Kathara thanks for replying, in protection I have these options: Select Locked Cells, Select Unlocked Cells, Format Cells, Format Columns, Format Rows, Insert Columns, Insert Rows, Insert Hyperlinks, Delete columns, Delete Rows, Sort, AutoFilter, Use PivotTable reports, Edit Objects, Edit scenarios. I only have the use of first two. Sure 2016 info might help as I may get it done in someone else's system.

Comment: Ok, I think there's a different menu even in 2007. Open the "File" tab. I don't know if it's the same in 2007 but is there an "Info" tab? If yes, there should be an option "Protect Workbook". Can you check this?

Comment: it seems to be different in 2007 version. Can you try the instructions here: http://www.uwec.edu/help/excel07/ws-protect.htm

Comment: @Kathara yes I did all that before asking the question. I don't need workbook level protection, need worksheet level protection in such way that the viewer is allowed to click/select some specific cells. What he/she selects, a formula elsewhere calculates a result. The formula uses the contents of the selected cell, hence I dont want the cell contents to be edited by viewers. But thats what excel is not allowing. By the way it is excel 2007 version that I am using. Why will I tell you otherwise? In your link go to section "Worksheet Level Protection". It is the same exact image of what I have

Comment: Sorry, but in 2016 version you can select what you want to protect from the "Protect Workbook"-Option. It's not that I did not understand you well but I'm trying to find your version's way of doing what seems so easy in my 2016-version. As I can't try out the options given (e.g. the instructions from the posted link) I can only ask you to do it and report back. Maybe someone with a 2007 version of excel may be better suited to help you.

Comment: @Kathara Its fine, I will try to find a way somehow, it is mostly the different ways in which your and my versions were designed, so certain stuffs aren't possible for me. Thanks a lot. By the way do you know why entering (9) or (5) in excel, makes it -9 or -5. I could not google out any help on that.

Comment: This would have to be a formatting issue, try to change the numbering format...

Comment: And it's highly possible that it's not possible to achieve what you want with the version you have :|